# What is (1) behind the split()?

Tags: function, vbscript

Could you help me to understand what is the (1) at the end of the below function?

```
Split(objWS.Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this Split method, your address is split with "$", where ever it comes.

So if Address is like `"Test $ New Street $ City"`  It will get split to an array

```
[0] "Test "
[1] " New Street "
[2] " City"
```

Using `Split(objWS.Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)` will get the data in the second position of the array like `" New Street "` in my example

Answer (score 2):

The `Split` function returns an `array`, which is effectively a list of values.  See here from the documentation:

> The Split function returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array that
>   contains a specified number of substrings.

The values in the array can be accessed using an *indexer*, whereby you specify that you wish to access an item at the defined position in the array.

In your case, you return the item at index 1, which is the *second item* in the array because the index of the array starts at 0.

In practical terms, if this were your array of length 6:

```
This
is
an
array
of
values
```

Position 0 would be `This`, position 1 (in your case) would be `is` and position 5 would be `values`.

Incidentally, the equivalent of this written in a longer way is

```
Dim MyArray()
Dim MyItem

' Split the address and store it in MyArray
MyArray = Split(objWS.Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")

' Get the second item from MyArray
MyItem = MyArray(1)
```

Comment: You don't need to declare a dynamic Array, because `Split()` returns a fixed array, just use `Dim MyArray`.